# Get dimensions.contentTop property value in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get the value of how much I have scroll from top of my page when I click.

I tried using following:

`contentTop` is returning the size of the screen which is 662. `this.content.scrollHeight;` is returning `1649` which is think is the total scrollable page height.

I am trying to use:

```
var isroll2 = this.content.getContentDimensions();
console.log(isroll2.dimensions.contentTop);
```

But above code is giving me error saying, what is wrong in my code? [Official document here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#getContentDimensions).

> [ts] Property 'dimensions' does not exist on type 'ContentDimensions'.

How do I get what I need?

`home.ts` code:

```
        ngAfterViewInit() {

            // Renderer2 used not Renderer, inject it before using
            this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (e) => {

              var isroll2 = this.content.getContentDimensions();
        // error in below line of code
              console.log(isroll2.dimensions.contentTop);

    // if i use below code it always returns 0
    alert(isroll2.contentTop);

    //below code is giving me total height of my screen which is 662
          let element = this.content.getScrollElement();
          alert(element.clientHeight);

// below line is returning 1649, which is total content length
 var iscroll =  this.content.scrollHeight;
alert(iscroll);

        ...// code here
```

Comment: Hi user2828442. I am a volunteer editor here, and I've noticed your questions come up a fair bit. I wonder if you could make the following small adjustments when you are writing questions (and especially since you are probably asking too many of them). (1) Use product/software names as they are written - it is Ionic, not IONIC in all caps (all caps is generally understood to be shouting, and is best avoided). (2) quote blocks are for quotes, and they are not a general highlighter. A quote is something that someone/something else said (e.g. in a speech, video, manual, book, etc).

Comment: (3) We prefer technical writing here, so please try to keep things succinct. There's no need to add thanks, advance thanks, please-help-me pleading, etc - this stuff tends to get trimmed out, so you'll be saving a future editor a bit of work if you can write it like that to start off with. Thanks!

Comment: (To expand upon my earlier point, I noticed you asked five questions on 13th September. Although the system rate-limits newer members, this is relaxed a bit once members acquire a few rep points. Nevertheless, this rate of asking makes me wonder if each post is getting sufficient research and prior personal effort before being asked - something to consider?)

Comment: Noted all of the above, will take care of the same

Comment: Thank you user2828442 `:=)`